# "-webkit-app-region: drag" only allowing drag in small region of element

Tags: css, webkit, node-webkit

I have a node-webkit page like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="titlebar"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

and css

```
#titlebar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

For some reason, I can only drag the upper ~3 pixels of the titlebar div (which is 40 px high). Bug or something I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hah, this is a bug(ish) that manifests only if the package.json file specifies `window.toolbar: true`. I had that set to `true` to access the dev tools.

Solution is to set `window.toolbar: false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `-webkit-user-drag` -

http://jsfiddle.net/clintioo/rpudce9w/5/

```
.titlebar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: element;
    user-drag: element;
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm going for. `-webkit-user-drag: element;` has no change in terms of desired behavior. Still only the top few pixels can be used to drag the window. (Also, because this is node-webkit, the -moz* and user-drag properties do nothing.)